# What part of speech is this?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

"youtuber" in "youtuber diet" (meaning a youtuber's diet) or any similar phrase. Is that an adjective?

Comment: A partial word wouldn't be any part of speech.

Comment: I would say youtuber is designating a type of diet, but that it is still a noun and you have a compound noun. Just like bath towel or fire hose, or countless others.

Comment: It can't be an adjective because an adjective has a comparative and superlative form, and *youtuber* does not. (There's no such thing as *a more youtuber diet*, or *the most youtuber diet*.) It can't be an adjective because an adjective can be modified by an adverb, and *youtuber* cannot. (There's no such thing as a *very youtuber diet* or a *surprisingly youtuber diet* or *too youtuber a diet*.) It can't be an adjective for other reasons, but I'm running out of space. You should start by checking the definition of an adjective. Why guess, and guess wrong, if you can just look it up?

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant "youtuber"...

Comment: RegDwigнt ♦, my question was what part of speech is it, I just threw my suggestion out there that this is an adjective. Apparently it's a noun adjunct, as was answered below.

Comment: [*Noun Adjunct*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attributive-nouns?sort=votes&pageSize=15) is probably the answer you're looking for. Google it on Wikipedia.

Comment: Mari-Lou A, yes, exactly :)

Comment: @RegDwigнt Would you please amend your comment? Although adjectives are usually gradable, the test is fallible. There's a whole class of nongradable adjectives which can't be compared that go by a variety of names in Garner's Modern English Usage, including [absolute adjectives](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-absolute-adjective-1689047), and even if this rule always held true, the grammatical test doesn't make sense with -er form words in and of itself, due to words where adding the suffix makes the comparative form: For instance, we don't say "more greater" because it's redundant.

Comment: @Tonepoet: The first part of your comment makes sense to me, but the second doesn't. "Youtuber" just happens to end with "-er". It doesn't end in the comparative "-er" suffix, so there is not a barrier in principle to it being made comparative by adding "-er" and it isn't redundant either (compare "tenderer" from "tender"; both forms exist and mean different things).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part of speech itself is a **noun**:

> (grammar, narrow sense) A word that can be used to refer to a person, animal, place, thing, phenomenon, substance, quality, or idea; one of the basic parts of speech in many languages, including English.
>
> ---
>
> This excerpt is taken from the Wiktionary entry for [Noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/noun), which is licensed under [CC-BY-SA 3.0.](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Even though it may seem as if it should be an adjective, because Youtuber is being used in a qualifying sense, it is possible because of *noun adjuncts*:

> In grammar, a noun adjunct or attributive noun or noun (pre)modifier is an optional noun that modifies another noun; it is a noun functioning as a pre-modifier in a noun phrase. For example, in the phrase "chicken soup" the noun adjunct "chicken" modifies the noun "soup". It is irrelevant whether the resulting compound noun is spelled in one or two parts. "Field" is a noun adjunct in both "field player" and "fieldhouse". — This excerpt is from Wikipedia's [Noun Adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) entry, and licensed under [CC-BY-SA 3.0 terms.](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

The manner in which I would like to demonstrate that it is a noun, rather than an adjective, is by means of its derivation. Most importantly, the combination of semantics and morphological restrictions largely demands it.

In order to simplify matters, I would like to defer to Collins English Dictionary—Complete and Unabridged 12th edition, to restrict the parts of speech which [Youtube](http://www.tfd.com/youtube) may have.

> YouTube (ˈjuːˌtjuːb)
> n[oun:]
> *trademark* a website on which subscribers can post video files
> v[er]b[:]
> (tr) to post (a video file) on the YouTube website.

I have reason to doubt the second definition is ever used legitimately. I would go into greater detail regarding that matter, but it is besides the point, which to show that Youtube in and of itself is never an *adjective* or *adverb*, which limits the possible functions of the -er suffix, which prevents the following definition from Webster's New International Dictionary (1910) from applying:

> 3. A suffix forming the comparative degree of adjectives and adverbs; as, warm*er*, soon*er*, swift*er*, quick*er*. …

This greatly reduces the number of possible applications. Although this fact does not prevent definition four from applying, I doubt it actually does apply, since a *frequentive* verb seems to be of a special class denoting an action with an inherently repetitive pattern, whereas posting a Youtube video may only happen once.

Now, having eliminated those two possibilities, *all of the other applications of the suffix* in Webster's New International Dictionary either or transform the applicable word classes into nouns, or retain noun status while a semantic distinction. Although at this point, I believe this suffices to answer the question, I would like address the two more likely likely meanings to apply in my opinion are derived from the primary sense as a noun. The first is is a member of the website youtube, and especially one who makes a profession out of it, based upon this definition:

1. A suffix forming: a Nouns from other nouns, with the sense of one who has to do with, esp. as a matter of trade, profession, occupation, function etc; as, tinn*er*, one whose occupation is with tin; hatt*er*, philolog*er*. …

In this case, it is only strictly necessary for somebody to have any association with the Youtube Website, but it does not hurt to point out that it is especially applicable somebody who has joined the [Youtube partnership program](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72851?hl=en) and make their living off of it would be a professional Youtuber. Yes, Youtube can be a legitimate profession, as the Forbes Article [The World's Highest Paid YouTube Stars 2015](https://www.forbes.com/sites/maddieberg/2015/10/14/the-worlds-highest-paid-youtube-stars-2015/#44f4e7203192) shows, with Pewdie Pie being the highest ranked multi-millionaire on the list. Somehow, he earns $12 million a year off of it.

The other definition which I think may apply is this:

> **c** Nouns from nouns or adjectives of place, denoting resident of, one living in; as, London*er*, southern*er*, villag*er*, foreign*er*.

This does not make much literal sense, but figuratively speaking, it should be remembered that Youtube is a website, and aside from the construction of the the word web*site*, there are many other factors that indicate websites are often treated as if they are places you can be @, go to and even inhabit as a netizen. In these metaphors, Youtuber would still be considered a noun.

Comment: I like this--just curious, in the first (1913) quotation, is it really _hater_ and not "hatter_?  One who hates, not one who makes hats?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write "youtuber". Noun adjunct is the answer I was looking for, though, thank you :)

Comment: @Xanne I can't be sure, since I have neither a hardcopy, nor access to scans and I suspect the transcriptions are mostly based upon a single source. Since I had to revise this answer to fit the change anyway, I've also changed my choice of dictionary due to the challenge and my own uncertainty, and it seems likely that hatter would have been the example used since 1909 wasn't so long before 1913.